# foldLeft : if exists add to a map else update values

Tags: scala

I wanted to try out the foldLeft similar to reduceByKey function.
If the letter exists increment by value else append the tuple in HashMap.

The below code fails:

```
val output = input.toLowerCase.filter(Character.isLetter).map(x => (x,1)).foldLeft(HashMap.empty[Char,Int].withDefaultValue(0)){case (acc,(x,y))=> acc += x   }
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by "the below code fails"? Does it compile? If not, then what's the compile error message you get? Does it run, but doesn't do what you expected? If yes, then what exactly did you expect (an example would help) and how does what it actually do differ from your expectation?

Comment: Provide more information `data`, `error you get` and the `expected output`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breaking down your code snippet:

```
.toLowerCase.filter(Character.isLetter)
```

As showcased in @jwvh's answer, this can be simplified to `.collect{case c if c.isLetter => c.toLower}`

```
.map(x => (x, 1))
```

This transformation is unnecessary if you intend to use `foldLeft`.

```
.foldLeft(HashMap.empty[Char,Int].withDefaultValue(0)){case (acc, (x,y)) => acc += x}
```

This wouldn't compile as `+=` is an assignment which cannot be applied to the accumulator.

For counting distinct characters in a string, your `foldLeft` can be formulated as shown below:

```
"abac".foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]()){
  case (m, c) => m + (c -> (m.getOrElse(c, 0) + 1))
}
// res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Int] = Map(a -> 2, b -> 1, c -> 1)
```

The idea is simple: in `foldLeft`'s binary operator, add to the existing Map `c -> m(c)+1` if `c` already exists; else `c -> 0+1`.

Answer (score 3):

With Scala 2.13 you can use the new `groupMapReduce()`.

```
val output = "In-Pint".collect{case c if c.isLetter => c.toLower}
                      .groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_+_)
//output: Map[Char,Int] = Map(p -> 1, t -> 1, i -> 2, n -> 2)
```

Comment: Thanks jwvh for the new function. Is groupMapReduce efficient than foldLeft?

Comment: Efficiency of the `fold` vs. `groupMapReduce` may be relevant, just as the choice of the transient collections is. If you `foldLeft` a very long collection by accumulating on a non-mutable `Map`, the performance issue may not come from the folding, but the mutation of the map at each iteration. By using a standard library method, you can (hope) that the library designers accounted for that. Anyway, it's good to think of efficiency, but if it really is performance critical, it's better to think... twice !